# screen remains black after given access in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, camera, barcode-scanner

I have an app which is basically loading a website or to be exact a search engine like google. This kind of search engine has some functionalities like saving products and also scan them over barcode scanner with webrtc. There I have persistent problem that i'm not really able to use the cam when I tap the area to activate it. After it asks for permission it remains black.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  WETID.de
//
//  Created by user931404 on 12/11/21.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView=WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate=self
        view = webView
        config.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    }

    @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!

    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://wetid.de")!
        
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
}
```

I tried many solutions like changing the structure and add some new configs as well as adding additonal options in info.plist but without success, does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: Show us the camera support code.

Comment: It's a webrtc which is already running over the website wetid.de

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. For webrtc your iOS target has to be 14.3 or higher. Do you have that?

Comment: From other resources I heard that it's technically possible for every version of ios to connect to webrtc over browser

Comment: that's just not true.

Comment: What kind of option will be the best then to make barcode scanner work on  webview?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242831/discussion-between-john-elemans-and-sparkm4n).

Comment: Did you solve it bro can you share the solution